# For each element, loop over all previous elements

Tags: machine-learning, jax

I have a 2D JAX array containing an image.

For each pixel `P[y, x]` of the image, I would like to loop over all pixels `P[y, x-i]` *to the left* of that pixel and reduce those to a single value. The exact reduction computation involves finding a particular maximum over a weighted sum involving those pixels' values, as well as `i` and `x`. Therefore, the result (or any intermediate results) for `P[y, x]` can't be reused for `P[y, x+1]` either; this is an O(x²y) operation overall.

Can I accomplish this somewhat efficiently in JAX? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

JAX does not provide any native tool to do this sort of operation for an arbitrary function. It can be done via `lax.scan` or perhaps `jnp.cumsum` for functions where each successive value can be computed from the last, but it sounds like that is not the case here.

I believe the best you can do is to combine `vmap` with Python for-loops to achieve what you want: just be aware that during JIT compilation JAX will flatten all `for` loops, so if your image size is very large, the compilation time will be long. Here's a short example:

```python
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import vmap

def reduction(x):
  # some 1D reduction
  assert x.ndim == 1
  return len(x) + jnp.sum(x)

def cumulative_apply(row, reduction=reduction):
  return jnp.array([reduction(row[:i]) for i in range(1, len(row) + 1)])

P = jnp.arange(20).reshape(4, 5)
result = vmap(cumulative_apply)(P)
print(result)
# [[ 1  3  6 10 15]
#  [ 6 13 21 30 40]
#  [11 23 36 50 65]
#  [16 33 51 70 90]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. I had tried that approach already and was hoping for more efficient option, but it looks like JAX isn't designed for this sort of thing. I'll be using a different approach to solve my problem instead.